# NetSuite - Generating Multiple Sales Orders from one Estimate (aka Quote)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is it possible to **generate two (or more) Sales Orders for one Quote/Estimate** in NetSuite?

When I ask if it's possible I mean without doing everything manually in SuiteScript.

Specifically we have a custom field added to the Opporutnity & Estimate transaction called custcol_hauler_rate and there are firm business rules disallowing a Sales Order to be generated with more than one distinct hauler rate.

I was hoping that there was a way to **transform a Quote** using a "filter". If I knew there were two distinct haul rates, say $10/ton and $15/ton, than in SuiteScript I could **perform two transform statements** one for the $10 items and one for the $15 items. This sounds too good to be true.

The number of distinct hauler rates on a Quote is usually one, but on it could be half a dozen so if that matters. Otherwise I am leaning towards splitting out the Quote using copy and plucking out items from the copied versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform a single Quote to Order multiple number of times. Without SuiteScript it wont be possible.

I would suggest write your own button using `beforeLoad` user event script.

Comment: Thanks to all that answered. I confirmed that a quote can be submitted to SO multiple times.Here is how I accomplished it. 1. zero quantities of quote lines that don't belong in first order, then transform the quote to an order using transform. Then set the quantity back to what it was and zero out the lines that have already gone to SO. Repeat until done, don't forget to reset all the quantity on the quote. So setting Qty to zero causes the line to stay on the quote but the line does not go to the SO, and if PO's are automatically created. My only worry is how to handle transaction all /none

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this.

I'm not sure you can transform a quote multiple times. I'd test that first.

You can use nlapiCopyRecord on the quotes though and filter out items by hauler rate.

Comment: Thanks, I might try. I did note that the Estimate changes to "Won" status when it is transformed to order but I don't think that prevents me from transforming another.